# как установить ogre3d из исходников в линуксе

Tags: linux, astra-linux, ogre

В общем столкнулся с проблемой как установить ogre3d из исходников в линуксе (в моём случае Astra linux).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. надо установить **cmake** и библиотеки

   sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev libvulkan-dev glslang-dev

   Также желательно эти

   sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev libxt-dev libxaw7-dev doxygen
2. Скачать [архив](https://www.ogre3d.org/) (я выбрал достаточно старый из за моего cmake-а , ogre-1.12.13.zip )
3. разархивировать , зайти в разархивированную папку консольной стройкой и ввести команды :

   cd Домашний/ogre/ogre-1.12.13
   mkdir build
   cd build
   cmake ..
   make
   sudo make install

   создаю папку билд, вызываю кумейк, и произвожу сборку, с последующей установкой.

После чего можно запустить простейший пример (правда я перезагружал компьютер для пущей надёжности)

**ogre_example1.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-08-26T17:23:57
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ogre_example1
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
    BasicTutorial1.cpp \



HEADERS += \

FORMS += \

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/OGRE/ \
                /home/dima/ogre/ogre-1.12.13/Components/Bites/include \
                /home/dima/ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include            \
                /usr/local/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem                \
                /usr/local/include/OGRE/Overlay



# -- из папки сборки все библы

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreBites

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreBitesQt

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreGLSupport

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreMain

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreMeshLodGenerator

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreOverlay

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgrePaging

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreProperty

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreRTShaderSystem

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreTerrain

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/ -lOgreVolume

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

## - a
#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/lib/libOgreGLSupport.a


#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain/ -lOgreMain_pch_dephelp

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/OgreMain/libOgreMain_pch_dephelp.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lfreetype

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libfreetype.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lpugixml

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libpugixml.a

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/ -lzzip

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/include

#unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../ogre/ogre-1.12.13/build/Dependencies/lib/libzzip.a



unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreBites

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreBitesQt

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreMain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreMeshLodGenerator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreOverlay

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgrePaging

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreProperty

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreRTShaderSystem

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOgreVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -lOpenThreads

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losg

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgAnimation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgDB

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgFX

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgGA

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgManipulator

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgParticle

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgPresentation

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgShadow

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgSim

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgTerrain

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgText

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgUI

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgUtil

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgViewer

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgVolume

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/local/lib/ -losgWidget

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/local/include
```

**BasicTutorial1.cpp**

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
This source file is a part of OGRE
(Object-oriented Graphics Rendering Engine)
For the latest info, see http://www.ogre3d.org/


Copyright (c) 2000-2013 Torus Knot Software Ltd
Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:


The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.


THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//! [fullsource]

#include "Ogre.h"
#include "OgreApplicationContext.h"
#include "OgreInput.h"
#include "OgreRTShaderSystem.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace Ogre;
using namespace OgreBites;

class BasicTutorial1
        : public ApplicationContext
        , public InputListener
{
public:
    BasicTutorial1();
    virtual ~BasicTutorial1() {}

    void setup();
    bool keyPressed(const KeyboardEvent& evt);
};


BasicTutorial1::BasicTutorial1()
    : ApplicationContext("OgreTutorialApp")
{
}


void BasicTutorial1::setup()
{
    // do not forget to call the base first
    ApplicationContext::setup();
    addInputListener(this);

    // get a pointer to the already created root
    Root* root = getRoot();
    SceneManager* scnMgr = root->createSceneManager();

    // register our scene with the RTSS
    RTShader::ShaderGenerator* shadergen = RTShader::ShaderGenerator::getSingletonPtr();
    shadergen->addSceneManager(scnMgr);

    // -- tutorial section start --
    //! [turnlights]
    scnMgr->setAmbientLight(ColourValue(0.5, 0.5, 0.5));
    //! [turnlights]

    //! [newlight]
    Light* light = scnMgr->createLight("MainLight");
    SceneNode* lightNode = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    lightNode->attachObject(light);
    //! [newlight]

    //! [lightpos]
    lightNode->setPosition(20, 80, 50);
    //! [lightpos]

    //! [camera]
    SceneNode* camNode = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();

    // create the camera
    Camera* cam = scnMgr->createCamera("myCam");
    cam->setNearClipDistance(5); // specific to this sample
    cam->setAutoAspectRatio(true);
    camNode->attachObject(cam);
    camNode->setPosition(0, 0, 140);

    // and tell it to render into the main window
    getRenderWindow()->addViewport(cam);
    //! [camera]

    //! [entity1]
    Entity* ogreEntity = scnMgr->createEntity("ogrehead.mesh");
    //! [entity1]

    //! [entity1node]
    SceneNode* ogreNode = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    //! [entity1node]

    //! [entity1nodeattach]
    ogreNode->attachObject(ogreEntity);
    //! [entity1nodeattach]

    //! [cameramove]
    camNode->setPosition(0, 47, 222);
    //! [cameramove]

    //! [entity2]
    Entity* ogreEntity2 = scnMgr->createEntity("ogrehead.mesh");
    SceneNode* ogreNode2 = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode(Vector3(84, 48, 0));
    ogreNode2->attachObject(ogreEntity2);
    //! [entity2]

    //! [entity3]
    Entity* ogreEntity3 = scnMgr->createEntity("ogrehead.mesh");
    SceneNode* ogreNode3 = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    ogreNode3->setPosition(0, 104, 0);
    ogreNode3->setScale(2, 1.2, 1);
    ogreNode3->attachObject(ogreEntity3);
    //! [entity3]

    //! [entity4]
    Entity* ogreEntity4 = scnMgr->createEntity("ogrehead.mesh");
    SceneNode* ogreNode4 = scnMgr->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode();
    ogreNode4->setPosition(-84, 48, 0);
    ogreNode4->roll(Degree(-90));
    ogreNode4->attachObject(ogreEntity4);
    //! [entity4]

    // -- tutorial section end --
}


bool BasicTutorial1::keyPressed(const KeyboardEvent& evt)
{
    if (evt.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
    {
        getRoot()->queueEndRendering();
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {
        BasicTutorial1 app;
        app.initApp();
        app.getRoot()->startRendering();
        app.closeApp();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred during execution: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

//! [fullsource]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]